# FullCalendar with custom view not working

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm working on a calendar application for a client. The calendar needs to show resources for each day of the week. I've managed to create a custom view in FullCalendar that shows all days of the week with no problem. But as soon as I add `hiddenDays: [0,6]` to the custom view, as my client does not work on those days, the navigation buttons stop working.

Here's my custom view code:

```js
resourceTimeGridWeekDay: {
              type: "resourceTimeGrid",
              buttonText: "weekdays",
              hiddenDays: [0,6],
              visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
                let start = new Date(currentDate.valueOf())
                let end = new Date(currentDate.valueOf())

                start.setDate(start.getDate() - start.getDay())
                end.setDate(start.getDate() + 7)

                return {start: start, end: end}
              }
            }
```

Without the `hiddenDays` attribute, everything works perfectly fine.

**EDIT:** When I change it to something like this, I can atleast navigate backwards but never forwards:

```js
resourceTimeGridWeekDay: {
              type: "resourceTimeGrid",
              buttonText: "weekdays",
              hiddenDays: [0,6],
              visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
                let start = new Date(currentDate.valueOf())
                let end = new Date(currentDate.valueOf())

                start.setDate(start.getDate() - start.getDay())
                if (currentDate.getDay() === 5) {
                  end.setDate(start.getDate() + 9)
                } else {
                  end.setDate(start.getDate() + 7)
                }

                return {start: start, end: end}
              }
            }
```

**EDIT 2:** I'm running FullCalendar version 5.5.0.

Comment: which version of fullCalendar is this? 4 or 5? And which point release? e.g. 5.3.1 or whatever? It helps to know, in case there is a bug in fullCalendar.

Comment: Whoops. Should have mentioned that. I was using 5.1.0. I've upgraded to 5.5.0 and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be clear...are you trying to create a "week" view? Because there's already one of those by default - resourceTimeGridWeek . Is your version meant to be different somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ADyson! Didn't realize there was a 'resourceTimeGridWeek' view. I probably accidentally skipped over it without realizing when I checked the documentation. I've substituted it in and it works like a charm now!

I needed a view that would show all days in the week and their resources, excluding Saturday and Sunday.

```js
resourceTimeGridWeekDay: {
              type: "resourceTimeGridWeek",
              buttonText: "weekdays",
              hiddenDays: [0,6],
              visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
                let start = new Date(currentDate.valueOf())
                let end = new Date(currentDate.valueOf())

                start.setDate(start.getDate() - start.getDay())
                if (currentDate.getDay() === 5) {
                  end.setDate(start.getDate())
                } else {
                  end.setDate(start.getDate() + 6)
                }
                // document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(end)

                return {start: start, end: end}
              }
            }
```

I had to keep the 'visibleRange' bit because otherwise it'd start the week on random days.